# How can I install software wihout the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: installation, software-center

How can I install Gnome Dictionary or other software if my Ubuntu Software Center is not working?

Please give me explanation why my software center is not working and how to fix it.

Comment: Run the command suggested by @onse in the answer below and **edit your question** with the copy/paste of errors you get if any. That will help us understand where the problem may be.

Comment: Here you are asking two questions: alternatives to the software center and how to fix it. Please only ask one question per post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the terminal and type `sudo apt-get install gnome-dictionary`.

Most probably the software center isn't the problem but apt is. Therefore, the formerly mentioned command should fail and tell you why through an error message.

On a side note: people's answers tend to be much more helpful when you provide more information about your problem. In your case, "is not working" is way to general. Please explain further what happens. Are you seeing error messages? If so, what do they say? Can you install other software or is only installing gnome-dictionary the problem?